# mgo $all query an array with an array and be case insensitive?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have an array of ingredient names that is dynamic and provided per user. I'd like to match it to `mongo` documents where there is an `array` of objects called `ingredients` which has a property `name`. I've written a query (see below) which will take query parameters from the URL and will return all the documents that have all matching ingredient names, however this search is case sensitive and I'd like it not to be.

I've considered using `bson.RegEx` with `Option: "i"`, however I'm not sure how to form this query or apply it to an array of strings.

Here is the case sensitive query:

```
// Check for ingredients, return all recipes that can be made using supplied ingredients
if qryPrms["ingredients"] != nil {
    mongodQ["ingredients.name"] = bson.M{"$all": qryPrms["ingredients"]}
}
```

`mongodQ` is the `bson.M` I use to query the collection later in the code. Ideally I could apply `RegEx` to each element in `qryPrms["ingredients"]` so it would return closely matching ingredients like `cheese` would return `swiss cheese` as well. This is also a more general `mongodb` question I suppose when it comes to querying with a dynamic array.

Comment: I would say use a Collator but the main branch of mgo does not support this feature it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using a `for` loop to build a `slice` of type `bson.RegEx`.

```
if qryPrms["ingredients"] != nil {
        var ingRegEx []bson.RegEx
        for i := range qryPrms["ingredients"] {
            ingRegEx = append(ingRegEx, bson.RegEx{Pattern: qryPrms["ingredients"][i], Options: "i"})
        }
        mongodQ["ingredients.name"] = bson.M{"$all": ingRegEx}
    }
```